# How get value of child node directly from root if you have child key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Android app.

I created a FireBase database which holds the information of registered user.

As you can see in the picture, I created costume key for users in my database which are users `User UID` in authentication section. When  user logged in, I get `User UID` and find its information in my `FireBase` database directly from root node to that particular node which always gives me the null value.

Kindly help me out.

If you can upload a code snippet, that would be highly appreciated.

[image: Database sample and location of problem].

Comment: If you have the UID then it should be easier for you to get the information. I guess your problem is that you are trying to access the information from the wrong level.  Please share your logic of accessing the information. Try this:- DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); String uri = ref.child("YOUR_UUID").child("imageUri").value();

Comment: I appreciate your response. I removed my code and run your proposed solution but it says there no method of .value(). Additionally at this point, it is not showing getValue method.

Comment: here is the code: auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String child = ds.getValue().toString();
                    System.out.println("child are :"+child);
                }

Comment: try my code but without `child("teacher")`

Comment: It gave me null pointer exception.

Comment: well you cant just query on the id you need the path to that id then you can query @MuhammadShoaib

Comment: Thank  you @PeterHaddad

Comment: In your code just don't apply for loop : onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) try to use this dataSnapshot directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("teacher");

ref.orderByKey().equalto(currentuser.getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           String value=dataSnapshot.child("teacherName").getValue().toString();

      }
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
}
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
}
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
}
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

Reference the location where you want to query then do `addChildEventListener` and query while having a condition equal to the user id that you got.

```
FirebaseUser currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response but I don't want to hard core 'teacher' on the top.Because I dont know at time of logging in that logged user is teacher or student.I know its user UID which used in database as a key  would tell me that what type of user it is?Is this the way to get values of that key directly?

Comment: oh then you can just loop on all the usersID, just do not reference `child("teacher")`

Answer (score 1):

To get the data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("teacher").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String ImageUri = dataSnapshot.child("ImageUri").getValue(String.class);
        String teacherName = dataSnapshot.child("teacherName").getValue(String.class);
        String teacher_key = dataSnapshot.child("teacher_key").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", ImageUri + "/" + teacherName + "/" + teacher_key);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which the `uid` is the id of the user that you say you already have.

Comment: Can I do it by ignoring the teacher Node?Because I don't know either it is teacher or student.I just knew its UID.I mean to stay if i have the address of some specific child node,is it possible to excess the values of that node by ignoring its parent?

Comment: You cannot ignore a node. Every node is a location in your Firebase database.

Comment: What can you do, is to let the user decide when loggin in, what kind of user is, a teacher or a student.